# force rds proxy to renew credentials on grant change?

Tags: amazon-rds

I'm using Mysql flavored Aurora with an RDS proxy in front. Most of the time life is good. Sometimes, however, I update a grant giving new new permissions to an account. At these times if I were directly connecting to the database, I could log out and log in again to get a refresh. With RDS proxy, the proxy keeps connections open all the time, so when I reconnect, it is not a new connection, but the same old one in disguise.

How can I, ideally programmatically from Terraform, tell RDS proxy, no, for real, new connection time?